# Arm assembly passing a string as a parameter

Tags: string, assembly, arm

If I have a format string like this:

```
fmtPrintSphere:.string "Sphere %s\n"
.global main
.balign 4
```

and another format string like this

```
fmtName1:.string "First"
.global main
.balign 4
```

when I call the fist one, how do I add in the second string as an argument? ie

```
adrp x0, fmtPrintSphere
add x0, x0, :lo12:fmtPrintSphere

mov x1, fmtName1 <-- this causes a segmentation fault

bl 'printf'
```

UPDATE:
this is how I'm calling the function

```
add x0, x29, fmtName1
add x1, x29, origin_offset
bl printSphere
```

this is what I have so far in the function

```
printSphere:
    stp  x29, x30, [sp, alloc]!
    mov  x29, sp

    mov x1, x0

    adrp x0, fmtPrintSphere
    add  x0, x0, :lo12:fmtPrintSphere


    bl printf



    mov w0, 0
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], -alloc
    ret
```

this does not throw any errors but the output is just: **Sphere**
it should be: **Sphere First**

UPDATE X2:
This is an example of what I'm trying to do -

```
void printSphere(char *name, struct sphere *s){
     printf("Sphere %s origin = (%d, %d, %d) radius = %d\n", name, s->origin.x, s->origin.x, s->origin.y, s->rad)
}
```

input:
printSphere("someName", $sphereStruct)

output:
Sphere someName = (2, 3, 4) radius = 10

Comment: What's `fmtName` (other than "not `fmtName1`")?

Comment: sorry, that's a typo it should be fmtName1, I will change that, the function can take either fmtName1 or fmtName2 as the first parameter

Answer (score 2):

Just like the the first symbol, you load the high bits of the address with `adrp` and add the low bits with `add`

```
adrp x1, fmtName
add  x1, x1, :lo12:fmtName
```

Or load the address directly from a constant pool

```
ldr x1, =fmtName
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more detail.

I don't actually have fmtName, just have the address of it stored in x0 before the function was called.

I've tried:

ldr x1, =x0

which gives the error: undefined reference to 'x0'

Comment: @Sentinel If you already have the address, why bother computing it again? `mov x1, x0`.

Comment: I've updated the original question. I now move x0 to x1 first and no longer get an error but the value doesn't seem to be printing.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
.data
        fmtPrintSphere:
                .string "Sphere %s\n"
        fmtName1:
                .string "First"
.text
        .global main
        .include "mymac_armv8.s"
main:
        nop
        bl write
_exit
write:
        push2 x29,x30
        ldr x0,=fmtPrintSphere
        ldr x1,=fmtName1
        bl printf
        pop2 x29, x30
        ret
```

OUTPUT:

```
alarm@alarm:~/aarch64 $ ./stuff
Sphere First
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the same function to print either fmtName1 or fmtName2. This is for an assignment and they want us to pass a character pointer as the first parameter to the function and the second parameter is for something else.

Comment: What is the criteria for your printf based function to print one thing or another thing? Are fmtName1 fmtName2 or just labels containing ASCII characters?

Comment: I'm not sure what it should look like in assembly but the equivalent c code looks like this

first = newSphere();
second = newSphere();
printSphere ("first", &first);
printSphere("second", &second);

Comment: Can you provide hypothetical outputs so it will make your goals clearer?  You appear to using four (4) distinct functions; two (2) to assign a value to first and second, respectively and two (2) printf based functions that will output the values for first and second.

Comment: I've updated the original question at the end with an example